# How to find scatter data in matplotlib's internal structures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am able to access the internal matplotlib data for `plot`s with the code below.

My question is: in which structure can I find the data related to scatter visualizations (that I execute with `plt.scatter()`?

Background: I have to perform some `...canvas.mpl_connect('axes_leave_event', leave_axes)` related stuff. Therefore I need access to these structures.

So: below is the code for accessing the internal structures of `plot()`. And I am looking how to access the internal structures for `scatter()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)

size = 10
a = np.random.random(size)
b = np.random.random(size)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, })

g = plt.plot(df.a, df.b, marker='o')

print("g[0].axes.lines[0].get_xdata()=", g[0].axes.lines[0].get_xdata())
plt.show()
```

results in:

```
g[0].axes.lines[0].get_xdata()= [4.17022005e-01 7.20324493e-01 1.14374817e-04 3.02332573e-01
 1.46755891e-01 9.23385948e-02 1.86260211e-01 3.45560727e-01
 3.96767474e-01 5.38816734e-01]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I want to use `scatter`. In the example I used `plot`, because at `plot` I know where to find the data points of the plot (and with `scatter` I do not know it yet). If you have an idea how I could rephrase my question to make this clearer, I am happy for edits of my post / suggestions :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the equivalent of what you did for `plot` is:

```
ax.collections[0].get_offsets()
```

This gives you a masked array, which contains the data in its `data` attribute.

For example:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = [4,5,6,5]
>>> y = [5,4,1,2]
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.scatter(x, y)
>>> ax.collections[0].get_offsets().data
array([[4., 5.],
       [5., 4.],
       [6., 1.],
       [5., 2.]])
```